# Is it more performant to use several for-loops by themself or to delegated the logic to promises?

Tags: javascript, performance, typescript, ecmascript-6, promise

Following scenario: A function gets 3 arrays of a certain length, each one of those needs to be iterated over to find a matching object. When the object is found, the for-loop breaks and the next one isn't called. The arrays can't be merged in this case. Basically like this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
  if (array1[i].id == matchingID) {
    returnValue = array1[i];
    break;
  }
}
if (!returnValue) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
    if (array2[i].id == matchingID) {
      returnValue = array2[i];
      break;
    }
  }
}
if (!returnValue) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array3.length; i++) {
    if (array3[i].id == matchingID) {
      returnValue = array3[i];
      break;
    }
  }
}
return returnValue;
```

Would using promises be more efficient in this case, since that way all for-loops can be worked at at the same time? Like this, with each function-call doing one of the for-loops (and resolving the found value) from the example above:

```
return new Promise((resolve) => {
  this.findMatchingIDInArray1(array1)
    .then(() => resolve(returnValue));
  this.findMatchingIDInArray2(array2)
    .then(() => resolve(returnValue));
  this.findMatchingIDInArray3(array3)
    .then(() => resolve(returnValue));
})
```

Which way is more perfomant? Is there better way to do this? Thanks for your help!

Comment: There's no reason to use promises because nothing in your function is asynchronous.

Comment: Promises are doing nothing here as you have no async code.

Comment: You meant to use `array…[i].id`, right?

Comment: You are performing linear search for O(n) in each `for` loop. If you're not changing *your algorithm*, you're not going to change that performance. If the arrays are sorted, then you can execute a binary search which *will* be faster. Then again, if the arrays don't have a lot of items, I don't think it would really matter that much. If you do have enormous amounts of data in each array, then a sort followed by a search optimised for sorted data could still give you a net performance boost. However, all that requires on *data* - don't do premature optimisation without testing first.

Comment: @Bergi yes, this is just an example that I wrote down really quick. Fixed!

Comment: @vlaz It doesn't go over huge amounts of data, it was just a question I asked myself after writing the code. Thanks for your input!

Comment: FYI, your example code is still broken. `array1[i].id = matchingID` is an assignment, not a comparison. In the future, please be sure your example code accurately reflects your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Would using promises be more efficient in this case, since that way all for-loops can be worked at at the same time?

No, you misunderstood what promises do. They're a tool to make *dealing with asynchronous code* easier. There is no asynchronous code in your use case, so you cannot make use of promises here. Promises do not "make" anything asynchronous, or even enable multithreading-like parallelism.

Answer (score 6):

> Would using promises be more efficient in this case, since that way all for-loops can be worked at at the same time?

No, because promises don't make anything asynchronous or parallel. They can only be used to **observe** things that are **already** asynchronous or parallel.

All that throwing promises at that code would do is change when the main thread blocks and add overhead.

If you need to offload or parallelize long-running computational tasks, look at [web workers](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/).

Answer (score 3):

The code would not be any more performant.

JavaScript is typically single-threaded (unless you use [web workers](https://www.w3.org/TR/workers/)), so your code wouldn't complete any more quickly using promises (because the loops wouldn't run in parallel)—in fact, if anything, it might be imperceptibly slower.

A promise is more of a way to handle the outcome of asynchronous code, and not a way to cause code to run asynchronously.

Comment: Correct—I've already mentioned in my answer that “the code in question does not do this.”

Comment: Fair point—it should say “if you made your looping code asynchronous...”.  Updated.

Comment: Yes, but if executed asynchronously, there's still a better chance (however small) that the execution won't take place at a critical time that the user would notice, no?

Comment: Making it `async` alone still would block the UI. You would also need to inject some `await`s with millisecond timeouts that allow for something else to run.

Comment: I've removed the third paragraph altogether.  Appreciate the feedback; my understanding of `async` was a little flawed.